# open and write file function / passing a variable to the function in c?

Tags: c, unix

Because i'm using the function of opening, reading and writing a file a lot i have the following

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include "header.h"
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>


int openfile()
{
char buffer[4096];
int input_file1;
char userInput = malloc(100);
int n;

if((input_file1 = open(userInput, O_RDONLY)) < 0) //opens file specified as userInput
{
    perror(userInput);
    exit(1);
}

while((n = read(input_file1, buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0) //reads file
{
    if((write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, n)) < 0) //writes to stdout
    {
        perror("failed to display file to output");
        close(input_file1);
        exit(1);
    }
}

}
```

Obviously the variable `userInput` is not set but i want to be able to...call this function in `main();` multiple times for potentially different userinputs.

how do i take a variable that is set in `main();` and pipe it into the below function?

so, in `main();` i'd call `openfile();` AFTER receiving an input that sets the userInput variable and then `openfile();` would write the file that was requested.

just looking to be pointed in the right direction, the answer is probably quite simple.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "pipe" a value to a function in C (like unix pipe). However, you can simply pass the `userInput` to your function `openfile()`.

```
int openfile( char *userInput)
{
 char buffer[4096];
 int input_file1;
 int n;
 .....
}
```

and pass it from `main()`:

```
int main(void)
{
char userInput[256];

/*read userInput here */   
openfile(userInput);   
....
return 0;
}
```

You could use a loop if you want to read multiple inputs and print them all.

```
int main(void)
{
int i;
char userInput[256];

for (i=0; i<10; i++)  { /* Reads 10 files */
  /*read userInput here */   
  openfile(userInput);   
}
....
return 0;
}
```

Comment: i did exactly this in the first place, but stupidly didn't define userInput as anything within `main();` so it was returning with a NULL value when trying to open a file and returning the error. i was just missing something super obvious. THANK YOU!